# Getting data of one window into popup window

Tags: javascript

I want to send data from one window to another. In onclick event this bit of code gets triggered:

```
var _popup;
if (!_popup) {
    _popup = window.open("/popup/index.html", "Keywords Source Table", "height=700, width=800");
} else {
    _popup.location.reload();
    _popup.focus();
}
    _popup.dataObj = data;
```

Then in other window I get this data with `window.dataObj`.

My problem is that I don't want to open a new window every time the click event gets triggered, but update the content of popup if it is already open. Initially it loads fine in initial open, but when I try to reload the content of already opened popup window with new data, the data is displayed as `undefined`.

Comment: Did you tried with making `_popup` global. Every time your click is triggered, you are freeing it with calling `var _popup;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Var x = window.open("");

x.passDataFuntion();

just have a global function in your popups JavaScript that you call from your child.